# How do I determine the voltage output of an antenna?

Tags: voltage, antenna

I have an antenna which I want to connect to a rectifier. How do I measure the AC from the antenna? I know it is very small, but the only measurement I have been able to take was the DC after running through the rectifier and with my body as additional resistance holding the multimeter leads to the rectifier output wires.

Comment: hm, that's not how RF works; you will need to define a load impedance, over which you could then observe a voltage. What frequencies are we actually talking about? The measurement setup for 72 GHz and 72 kHz will look **very** different and will have a cost ratio of roughly 10⁶ between them.

Comment: and what you observed with the multimeter was probably interference picked up from the power lines around you :)

Comment: Different RF signals have different voltages induced in the antenna, it could be anywhere in micro volts to milli volts.. The power absorbed by antenna could be in uW to mW range.  Probably your at home multimeter cannot measure it as it can just pick some radiation from something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To measure the voltage from an antenna you need to do it at a specific frequency and impedance.

You don't normally measure it directly, you're usually interested in a received signal level. A radio receiver may have a signal level meter that measures a voltage  somewhere in the receive signal path, often at the detector. These usually give a relative signal level, not an exact voltage. To get that you would need something more a bit more sophisticated.

If you want to measure a signal directly from an antenna a multimeter is probably going to be useless. The frequencies involved will be too high and the voltage levels too low for a multimeter to work. You might be able to use a frequency selective RF voltage meter to do it.

One other way would be to use a spectrum analyzer, you would connect the antenna to the analyzer through an appropriate cable and impedance matching if needed, and then the signal level at the frequency of interest would be read from the display.